# how to pipe the output of a command (let's say ipconfig) in another cmd window?

Tags: windows-command-prompt

"Commands that provide a lot of information should be run in a separate command shell with output piped through a pager (the “more” command), and with an appropriate title on the second command window.  " This is what i am supposed to do.

Comment: ipconfig.exe |<-"Pipe" sign here more. Try `ipconfig | more`

Comment: i've already tried that but it just displays the output one screen at a time, instead of a different shell. @Anubioz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **how to pipe the output of a command (let's say ipconfig) in another cmd window?**

It sounds like you want to execute a command from a command prompt window but have that open in a separate command window and also give a specific title to that new command prompt window (see below example).

### EXAMPLE

```
SET Command=IPCONFIG
SET Title=This is what i am supposed to do

START "" "CMD /K TITLE "%Title%" & %Command%"
```

Answer (score 0):

`start cmd /k` then the command

example: `start cmd /k ipconfig /all`

Comment: i also need to add a title to the new shell @Mass